# Bootstrap typeahead autocompletion with the source loaded only once on pageload

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I want to load the whole source data via jquery from the server but only once on pageload. I want to store it in a variable. The jquery part works but the input does not autocomplete. It does nothing. It works only if the source is written like source: ["blablabla","dadadada"].

This is my Javascript Code:

```
var datasource;          // this is the variable where my source will be stored

$.post("typeahead.php",
  {
    query: 'query'       // 'query' has no meaning ;)
  }, 
  function(data) {       // data looks like ["asd","fds"] thanks to json_encode on the server side
    datasource = data;
});

$('#searchInput').typeahead( {
  source: datasource
});
```

Server Side php code:

```
    /* connect to the db */
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","fahrschulesql1","******");
    if (!$con)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    // Select Database
    $db_selected = mysql_select_db("fahrschulesql1", $con);
    if (!$db_selected) {
        die ("Select DB error: " . mysql_error());
    }
    $query = "SELECT Vorname, Nachname FROM Benutzer b, Fahrlehrer f WHERE b.BenutzerID = f.BenutzerID";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die ("MySQL-Error: " . mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $array[] = $row["Vorname"] . " " . $row["Nachname"]; 
    }
    echo json_encode($array);
    mysql_close($con);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using Twitter Bootstrap v2.1?

Comment: I just updated my answer. Feel free to try it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are losing the reference to the array `datasource` by assigning a new array. You will need to manipulate the array to avoid losing the reference to it.

```
var datasource = [];

$.post("typeahead.php", {
    query: 'query'
}, function(data) {
    /* Add the responses to the datasource, don't mess up the reference */
    [].push.apply(datasource, data);
});

$('#searchInput').typeahead({
    source: datasource
});
```

[**See it here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/7f4Mc/)

---

Another option is caching the response. I personally prefer this method over the previous one.

You can use the `process` callback after sending the first request and cache the data. Onwards, use the cached data.

```
var cachedsource = (function(){
    var datasource = null;
    return function(query, process){
        if(datasource !== null) {
            /* use cached data */
            return datasource;
        } else {
            $.post("typeahead.php", {
                query: 'query'
            }, function(data) {
                /* cache data */
                datasource = data;
                process(datasource);
            });
        }
    };
})();
```

```
$('#searchInput').typeahead({
    source: cachedsource
});
```

[**See it here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/JBAS2/)

---

PHP is returning incorrect `Content-Type`. Try `$.ajax` instead of `$.post`.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "typeahead.php", 
  data: {
    query: 'query'
  },
  success: function(data) {
    /* cache data */
    datasource = data;
    process(datasource);
  },
  dataType: "json"
});
```

Notice the `dataType` is set to `json`.

You can also set the correct `Content-Type` in PHP using [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: I used your cached version and it seems to run well but this is what I got:  http://www.abload.de/img/typeahead4wje6.jpg

Comment: @XHotSniperX, update your question with your server side script. Because, both options listed here works

Comment: @XHotSniperX, can you log the contents of `data` in the success handle of `$.post`? I'm afraid this problem may be unrelated to the typeahead script

Comment: your first method gives an error: Uncaught TypeError: Function.prototype.apply: Arguments list has wrong type.

alert(data) in callback function posts this: ["Marc Tarnutzer","Michael Schumacher"]. exactly what I want.

Comment: @XHotSniperX, well, your source doesn't match. You have three results in the screenshot when it is suppose to be only two. You are overwritten it somewhere. Better paste your complete code then, no snippets. This is taking too much time

Comment: @XHotSniperX, updated my answer. Try `$.ajax` with explicit `dataType` setted

Comment: Now it works. I had to put header('Content-Type: application/json'); before echo in php file and then it worked. I didn't change the cachedsource method :) thaaank youu

Comment: This helped me too -- but I think there's a bug -- needs `process(datasource);` in the used cache source branch before returning.

Answer (score 0):

where is your html code?

are you using this:

```
<input id="searchInput" type="text" data-provide="typeahead">
```

?

then be sure your callback is ok in firebug and data is returned cause you didn't specified any url for example here:

```
$.post("typeahead.php",
```

then be sure you are running your js inside document.ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//do my js
});
```

also try:

`console.log(datasource);` before passing that var to the bootstrap plugin

definitely try this:

```
$(function(){

$.post("typeahead.php",
  {
    query: 'query'       // 'query' has no meaning ;)
  }, 
  function(data) {       // data looks like ["asd","fds"] thanks to json_encode on the server side
    $('#searchInput').typeahead( {
  source: data
});
});

});
```

Comment: Yeah I am using this
    <input id="searchInput" placeholder="Fahrlehrer suchen" type="text" autocomplete="off" data-provide="typeahead">

Comment: Yep in Chrome tools I can see that the response is:
["blablabla","blablabla"]

Comment: interesting and what when typing inside input? any error in console? :P

Comment: no there is no error. it does not autocomplete. it is like a normal input text input field. it works only when I write "source: ["asdfasd","sdfsadh"...].
I also did this http://www.lukeschreur.com/posts/bootstrap-asynchronous-auto-complete-input-fields but it is not working correctly. Do I have to convert JSON to an array?

Comment: nope i think you should try dumping data to check if it is returned into the plugin, try **console.log(datasource);** when request is finished before to pass it to the plugin, are you running all the js inside the document.ready ?

Comment: yes all the js files are included. bootstrap-typeahead.js and jquery.js... 
console.log(datasource);
["Marc Tarnutzer","Michael Schumacher"]
undefined

Comment: undefined is the problem so

Comment: what's after schumacher in your array? maybe this is a server side problem, php problem when generating array ?

Comment: but datasource contains ["Marc Tarnutzer","Michael Schumacher"]. What is wrong with that?

Comment: you posted :  console.log(datasource); ["Marc Tarnutzer","Michael Schumacher"] undefined -> this undefined at the end will broke the script

Comment: ok but if is there a *undefined* in your response the script will not work, can you confirm there is *undefined* after you array in data returned??

Comment: ok after trying your code above it shows me only the first letter for example "m" but does not autocomplete.