# Reading JSON with $.getJSON

Tags: jquery, json, adobe-edge

For a college assignment I have to read JSON data into an Adobe Edge project. In the JSON below you will see I made an array of colors. A function `setElementsColor(color)` has to look up the correct object in the `Colors` array of the json file. So the argument `color` has to be equal the `colorName` of the object. I am not quite sure how to do this.

Here is the JSON:

```
{
    "Colors": [
        {
            "colorName": "Black",
            "imageName": "fridge_black.jpg",
            "footerName": "black_footer.png",
            "facebookLogo": "black_facebook.png",
            "twitterLogo": "black_twitter.png",
            "linkedinLogo": "black_linkedin.png"
        },
        {
            "colorName": "Blue",
            "imageName": "fridge_blue.jpg",
            "footerName": "blue_footer.png",
            "facebookLogo": "blue_facebook.png",
            "twitterLogo": "blue_twitter.png",
            "linkedinLogo": "blue_linkedin.png"
        }
    ]
}
```

The following function is used to read out the JSON-file.

```
function setElementsColor(color){
  $.getJSON('json/colors.json',function(data){
    //The JSON must be read out here
  });
}
```

Comment: your json object seems to be valid on a linter. did you try a simple $.get('json/colors.json', function(data) { /*data.colors*/ }, 'json'); ? it could also come from the content-type header of the json file you request. It should be "application/json"... try to check this.

Comment: Check the [API reference](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/). Your JSON is already decoded in `data`.

Comment: @y_nk how do you change content-type header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use [`$.grep`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/).

```
function setElementsColor(color){
  $.getJSON('json/colors.json',function(data){
    var obj = $.grep(data.Colors, function(color) {
      return color.colorName === color;
    });
    /* Use obj */
  });
}
```

I'd be easier if `Colors` were an Object instead of an Array.

**Disclaimer:** Untested.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable answer. However, it seems the getJSON function doesn't work.

Comment: @SylvainVansteelandt, that's strange. Probably you can try `$.ajax` directly. Or, check [this previous answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14047889/417685), it explains how to force a JSON data type in `$.ajax`

Comment: Problem Solved, I ran the JSON in a validator and there was a comma after the last object.